# ajax validate specific column in cakephp 3

Tags: ajax, validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.4

I'm working in CakePHP 3.4

I have a `users` model and columns having `username`, `email`, `mobile`, `name` and `password`. `username`, `email` and `mobile` fields are having some validation rules including all three are unique value.

I'm using Ajax call on change of field value to validate fields with with custom function like `ajaxValidateUsername()` which checks for all validation rules manually in action and thus the validation rules specified in model is not being utilized.

**Can I have validation for specific field using ajax and return the error message as specified in the validation rule in `Users` model ?**

Till now, I have implemented this in `ajaxValidateUsername() with some modification from documentation

```
$validator = new Validator();
$errors = $validator->errors($this->request->getData('username'));
```

But, It is not working.

Comment: Why not doing a normal patching and returning the errors of the entity then instead? Much cleaner and consistent with the current cake way.

Comment: I think that will validate all fields which are set to `notEmpty` because rest of fields might be empty that moment  I wanna validate only one field

Comment: Cakephp 3.x lets you create validation objects on the fly. if you only need to validate 1 field, I would point your ajax to an action that builds the validator for that field and validates the data against the rules. https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#creating-validators

Comment: @AnujTBE have you added any rules to your newly instantiated validation object? eg `$validator->notEmpty('username', 'Please fill this field')` before calling the `errors()` method?

Comment: Do I need to re instantiate this again in controller ? I have already added validation rules to `UsersTable.php` and just want to call them for specific column

Comment: On patching you can set a "fields" list, so still only the desired fields would be validated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CakePHP 3.x you can create different validation sets and use them when patching your entity. See the [docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html#using-a-different-validation-set).

So you could create a method in your Controller which only validates some properties.

```
class UsersTable extends Table
{
    public function validationUsername($validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->add('username', 'notEmpty', [
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => __('Please specify a username.'),
            ])
            ->add(…);
        return $validator;
    }
}
```

And use this validation method in your controller.

```
$entity = $this->Users->newEntity(
    $this->request->getData(),
    ['validate' => 'username']
);
$success = !$entity->errors();
```

Comment: Exactly what I was saying all along :) Thanks for putting it into detail. But you don't even need multiple validators. Using `'fields' => ['username']' suffices when patching :)

Comment: @mark can you give an example of how to use `'fields' => ['username']` ?

Comment: Just `$this->Users->patchEntity($user, ['fields' => ...]);` - Nothing else required.